# MySQL : How to merge two tables with a column?

Tags: mysql

every one.

I have 2 tables.

tbl_a

```
id    Col_A   Col_B
1     1       2
3     3       4
```

tbl_b

```
id    Col_C   Col_D
1     100     101
2     102     103
4     104     105
```

I want to make a table such as:

```
id    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Col_D
1     1       2       100     101
2     0       0       102     103
3     3       4       0       0
4     0       0       104     105
```

I tried the SQL from [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql), but it wasn't the right result I want.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_a
LEFT  JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl_a
RIGHT JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
```

Result:

```
id     Col A  Col B   id(1)   Col C     Col D
1      1      2       1       100       101
3      3      4       (NULL)  (NULL)    (NULL)
(NULL) (NULL) (NULL)  2       102       103
(NULL) (NULL) (NULL)  4       104       105
```

How can I get the correct result?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT tbl_a.id, 
    tbl_a.Col_A, 
    tbl_a.Col_B, 
    COALESCE(tbl_b.Col_C, 0) AS Col_C, 
    COALESCE(tbl_b.Col_D, 0) AS Col_D
    FROM tbl_a
    LEFT  JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
    UNION
    SELECT tbl_b.id, 
    COALESCE(tbl_a.Col_A, 0) AS Col_A, 
    COALESCE(tbl_a.Col_B, 0) AS Col_B, 
    tbl_b.Col_C, 
    tbl_b.Col_D
    FROM tbl_a
    RIGHT JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
)
AS a 
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af0781/2) to this... and what is [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) .... 

Comment: Thank you for your quick and perfect answer, aRvi.
And thank for Luuk, too.
You saved my time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(tbl_a.id, tbl_b.id) AS id,
    IFNULL(tbl_a.Col_A, 0) as Col_A,
    IFNULL(tbl_a.Col_B, 0) as Col_B,
    IFNULL(tbl_b.Col_C, 0) as Col_C,
    IFNULL(tbl_b.Col_D, 0) as Col_D
FROM
    tbl_a
       LEFT JOIN
           tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id 
UNION 
SELECT 
     IFNULL(tbl_a.id, tbl_b.id) AS id,
     IFNULL(tbl_a.Col_A, 0) as Col_A,
     IFNULL(tbl_a.Col_B, 0) as Col_B,
     IFNULL(tbl_b.Col_C, 0) as Col_C,
     IFNULL(tbl_b.Col_D, 0) as Col_D
 FROM
     tbl_a
       RIGHT JOIN
         tbl_b ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
```